# Powershell Script help : Windows events to Query and export to excel

Tags: powershell, scripting, vbscript

I have below powershell script for windows events to query, trying to write this script to get the Compueter name, Event ID, Source and description info to excel.

```
$servers = get-content “c:\list.txt”
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
$server
Get-EventLog -LogName APPLICATION |Source "ACECLIENT" AND Where-Object { $_.EventID -eq 1001 } # I am not sure how to include here description "looking for 'File not found: C:\Program Files\Microsoft ISA Server\SDCONFIG.'" 
}
```

Looking for help to finish this script. This script to run on list of computers also.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $servers = get-content “c:\list.txt”
 $OututPath="C:\tst.csv"

 $start=[datetime]::Now.AddDays(-5)
 Get-EventLog -LogName Application -ComputerName $servers -Source "ACECLIENT" -Message "*File not found*" -After $start  | select MachineName, EventID, Message | Export-Csv $OututPath -NoTypeInformation
```

hope I understood what you do you want to filter

Comment: 've made some change to speed up. I think you need to make sure source name "ACECLIENT" is correct and change the where statement to meet your filter requirement. I'm not sure what log message your are looking for.

Comment: I have done small changes to get the last five days events only but the script not showing any results.... Can any one help me here... pls...

Comment: <Code>
$servers = get-content “C:\list.txt”
$OututPath="C\OUTPUT.csv"
$fromtime = (get-date).Adddays(-5)
get-eventlog -log Application -comp $servers | where {$_.source -eq "Defrag" -AND $_.EventID -eq 258 -and $_.message -like "*The disk defragmenter successfully*" -AND $_.TimeGenerated -EQ $FROMTIME  } | Export-Csv $OututPath -NoTypeInformation
<code>

Comment: # The Problem is I want to get the events for only last 5 days, When i added "-AND $_.TimeGenerated -EQ $FROMTIME" the output is not comming it is taking lot of time but not results. I think some logic problem.. Can any one help me here...